# How to change image using .on click event with 4 button as trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need your guys help here.
So,here is my condition. I have 4 buttons to trigger images, when the button clicked they will have active (I'm good with this one - but let me know if there is better way),

**SCENARIO:**
When I click on button 2, I want "image2" appear (have class="active"). 
Then if I click on button 3, the "image2" fadeout (remove class active) and add class active to "image3"

lets say this is my **4 buttons** :

```
<div id="button">
  <div class="trigger button-1" data-target="0"></div>
  <div class="trigger button-2" data-target="1"></div>
  <div class="trigger button-3" data-target="2"></div>
  <div class="trigger button-4" data-target="3"></div>
</div>
```

and I have another section for **images** that wrapped like this:

```
<div id="images-container">
  <img src="image-1" class="image1">
  <img src="image-2" class="image2">
  <img src="image-3" class="image3">
  <img src="image-4" class="image4">
</div>
```

I was thinking there is someway I can get the images in jQuery using data element?

My current jQuery:

```
var img = $('#images-container img'),
    trigger = $('.trigger');

// click this, make active, other? no
trigger.on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');

    // image that have the selected ID, active.
    // other images must remove active classes
    var a = $(this).data('target');
    $('#image-container').find('img').eq(a).addClass('active');

            // and help me from here guys!
```

I know this is maybe easy, but I'm not the jQuery pro. 
Every solutions will appreciated, and +1 FOR the REAL SOLUTION

Comment: Where does `.space-images` come from?

Comment: oops, it's wrong. Haha.. I change the code when I posted in stackoverflow. Sorry. Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add data atrribute to your html which relates to the respective imageclass... and addclass...

try this

**HTML**

```
<div class="trigger button-1" data-target="0" data-imageclass="image1"></div>
<div class="trigger button-2" data-target="1"  data-imageclass="image2"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 var img = $('#images-container img'),
 trigger = $('.trigger');

 // click this, make active, other? no
trigger.on('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');

  $('#images-container img').removeClass('active');
  $('.'+$(this).data('imageclass')).addClass('active');
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/HZgU9/)

i don't know why is `data-target` there but if your are not using that in your codes..then i guess you can use that instead of creating new data attribute..

```
$('.'+$(this).data('target')).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Hey, almost there, I don't why know it's doesnt work in my image. Will try double check now.

Comment: Seems like, you missed something. Because now my all images is has no active class at all?

Comment: Yes, already check it. and seems like there is no error in my console.
I understand your idea using .data('imagesclass'). Already console.log it also, it should works. But my image have no class now.. wierd<br>
when I delete $('#images-container img').removeClass('active'); my images not got active class.

Comment: this is gettin interesting,, let me check ok

Comment: ok here you go fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/HZgU9/  ..this is workinf\g fine

Comment: let me know if problem exists still.. :)

Comment: Oh yeah!!!! It's work. Thanks man! could you vote up my question , so I got another 2 points reputation for vote up your answer. :)

Comment: welcome... i already did.. :)...glad it helped... happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your simple case, I think just using tag position indexes is enough. Normally, if the trigger buttons and target images are the same number then this should work, as they will share the same position indexes.

Check this out:

```
var img = $('#images-container').find('img'),
    trigger = $('.trigger');

$('#button').on('click', '.trigger', function(e) {
    var self = $(this), // this trigger tag
        selfIndex = self.index(); // position of this trigger tag

    img.removeClass('active'); // remove class active from all img(s)
    img.eq(selfIndex).addClass('active'); // add class active just on this img

    trigger.removeClass('active'); //r emove class active from all trigger(s)
    self.addClass('active'); // add class active just on this trigger

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

But if you wanna use data attributes then do this: add value to your buttons' data attribute like this:

```
<div id="button">
  <div class="trigger button-1" data-target="image1"></div>
  <div class="trigger button-2" data-target="image2"></div>
  <div class="trigger button-3" data-target="image3"></div>
  <div class="trigger button-4" data-target="image4"></div>
</div>
```

Then in JS/jQuery, do this:

```
var img = $('#images-container').find('img'),
    trigger = $('.trigger');

$('#button').on('click', '.trigger', function(e) {
    var self = $(this);

    img.removeClass('active'); // remove class active from all img(s)
    img.filter('.' + self.data('target')).addClass('active'); // add class active just on this img

    trigger.removeClass('active'); //r emove class active from all trigger(s)
    self.addClass('active'); // add class active just on this trigger

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: I already tried bipen's code and sorry I'm not trying yours. but when I look in your code, it should work. Maybe without e.preventDefault() is fine, I have no anchor on it :)<br>
Thanks again!

=== edited===
your e.preventDefault() will be important if I have animation on it, great!